# Getting full indexes of a patch using libgit2 / git2go

Tags: git, go, patch, libgit2, pygit2

git2go's git.Patch or libgit2's git_patch returns a String value of the following format:

```
"diff": "diff --git a/test b/test
         index 9daeafb..dced80a 100644  
         --- a/test 
         +++ b/test 
         @@ -1 +1,3 @@  
         test
         +  
         +test"
```

Notice that `index 9daeafb..dced80a 100644` is not the full index. Is there anyway using libgit2 / git2go to return the full index? i.e. the equivalence of running `git diff --full-index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've managed to get some outside help. If anyone runs into the same issue, it can be returned using:

`git_diff_options` in libgit2 and setting `id_abbrev` to 40.
https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_diff_options

or `DiffOptions` in git2go and setting `IdAbbrev` to 40.
https://godoc.org/github.com/libgit2/git2go#DiffOptions